# Problemas al usar datos asíncronos en Highcharts utilizando Angular

Tags: angular, highcharts, asincronismo, programacion-asincrona

Gracias por molestarte en entrar a la pregunta.

Mi problema principal es el manejo de datos asíncronos a la hora de la creación de la gráfica. En concreto estoy utilizando network-graph >>> Funciona okai en todos los tests que he hecho síncronos (metiendo los datos a cholón para que nos entendamos). Mi problema es que el gráfico se crea antes de que reciba los datos (normal ya que es una peticion http lo que hay por detras) pero a la hora de añadir los datos el Chart no se actualiza (se queda con los datos en blanco que recibe de serie).

Los datos los recibo correctamente, pero para cuando los recibo ya he creado el gráfico y no se actualiza >>> En el ngOnInit tengo un console.log con chartOptions y aparecen los datos okai.

Este sería el interior de mi clase:

```
   Highcharts = Highcharts; 
    chartConstructor = "chart"; 

    chartView = true;

    updateFlag = false; 
    oneToOneFlag = true; 
    runOutsideAngular = false;

    network_links: any[] = [];
    network_nodes: any[] = [];

    chartOptions: any = {
        chart: {
            type: 'networkgraph',
            height: (9 / 16 * 100) + '%'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Relations '
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'APP - PURPOSE - PISCOPE - API'
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        plotOptions: {
            networkgraph: {
                keys: ['from', 'to'],
                layoutAlgorithm: {
                    enableSimulation: false,
                    integration: 'verlet',
                    linkLength: 100
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            id: 'language-tree',
            marker: {
                radius: 13
            },
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                textPath: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                linkFormat: '',
                allowOverlap: false
            },
            nodes: this.network_nodes,
            data: this.network_links
        }]
    }

    constructor( private service: FourPCertService) {}
  
    ngOnInit() {

        Highcharts.setOptions({
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    animation: {
                        duration: 0
                    },
                    
                }
            }
        });
        

        this.service.getDataB().subscribe( async (res: any) => { 
            await this.updateChartData(res.network_data.network_links, res.network_data.network_nodes);
            console.log(this.chartOptions);
        }, (e) => {
            console.log(e.message);
        });

    }

    updateChartData(links: any[], nodes: any[]){
        this.chartOptions.series[0].links = links;
        this.chartOptions.series[0].data = nodes;
    }
```

En resumen >>> No se como manejar datos asíncronos en Highcharts con Angular ya que crea el gráico antes de que los datos "buenos" se relacionen a él.

Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.

Answer (score 1):

mira puede hacer lo siguiente (este ejemplo no esta hecho en Angular), pero lo puedes adaptar a angular:

En este ejemplo estoy implementando ajax:  Asynchronous JavaScript And XML

---

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

    chart: {
        scrollablePlotArea: {
            minWidth: 700
        }
    },

    data: {
        csvURL: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/highcharts/highcharts@v7.0.0/samples/data/analytics.csv',
        beforeParse: function (csv) {
            return csv.replace(/\n\n/g, '\n');
        }
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Daily sessions at www.highcharts.com'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source: Google Analytics'
    },

    xAxis: {
        tickInterval: 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000, // one week
        tickWidth: 0,
        gridLineWidth: 1,
        labels: {
            align: 'left',
            x: 3,
            y: -3
        }
    },

    yAxis: [{ // left y axis
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        labels: {
            align: 'left',
            x: 3,
            y: 16,
            format: '{value:.,0f}'
        },
        showFirstLabel: false
    }, { // right y axis
        linkedTo: 0,
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        opposite: true,
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        labels: {
            align: 'right',
            x: -3,
            y: 16,
            format: '{value:.,0f}'
        },
        showFirstLabel: false
    }],

    legend: {
        align: 'left',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        borderWidth: 0
    },

    tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        crosshairs: true
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function (e) {
                        hs.htmlExpand(null, {
                            pageOrigin: {
                                x: e.pageX || e.clientX,
                                y: e.pageY || e.clientY
                            },
                            headingText: this.series.name,
                            maincontentText: Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y', this.x) + ':<br/> ' +
                                this.y + ' sessions',
                            width: 200
                        });
                    }
                }
            },
            marker: {
                lineWidth: 1
            }
        }
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'All sessions',
        lineWidth: 4,
        marker: {
            radius: 4
        }
    }, {
        name: 'New users'
    }]
});
```

```css
.highcharts-figure, .highcharts-data-table table {
    min-width: 360px; 
    max-width: 800px;
    margin: 1em auto;
}

.highcharts-data-table table {
    font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
    margin: 10px auto;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
}
.highcharts-data-table caption {
    padding: 1em 0;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #555;
}
.highcharts-data-table th {
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 0.5em;
}
.highcharts-data-table td, .highcharts-data-table th, .highcharts-data-table caption {
    padding: 0.5em;
}
.highcharts-data-table thead tr, .highcharts-data-table tr:nth-child(even) {
    background: #f8f8f8;
}
.highcharts-data-table tr:hover {
    background: #f1f7ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/series-label.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>

<!-- Additional files for the Highslide popup effect -->
<script src="https://www.highcharts.com/samples/static/highslide-full.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.highcharts.com/samples/static/highslide.config.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.highcharts.com/samples/static/highslide.css" />

<figure class="highcharts-figure">
    <div id="container"></div>
    <p class="highcharts-description">
        Chart showing data loaded dynamically. The individual data points can
        be clicked to display more information.
    </p>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

Detecté mi problema >> Estaba asignando los valores a chartOptions en la inicializacion de la variable.

Actualmente se ve asi mi codigo y funciona ok:

```
  Highcharts = Highcharts; // required
    chartConstructor = "chart"; // optional string, defaults to 'chart'

    chartView = true;

    updateFlag = false; 
    oneToOneFlag = true; 
    runOutsideAngular = false;

    chartOptions: any;

    constructor( private service: FourPCertService) {}
  
    ngOnInit() {

        Highcharts.setOptions({
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    animation: {
                        duration: 0
                    },
                    
                }
            }
        });

        this.service.getDataB().subscribe( async (res: any) => { 
            await this.updateChartData(res.network_data.network_links, res.network_data.network_nodes);
            console.log(this.chartOptions);
        }, (e) => {
            console.log(e.message);
        });

    }

    updateChartData(links: any[], nodes: any[]){
        this.chartOptions = {
            chart: {
                type: 'networkgraph',
                height: (9 / 16 * 100) + '%'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Relations '
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'APP - PURPOSE - PISCOPE - API'
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            plotOptions: {
                networkgraph: {
                    keys: ['from', 'to'],
                    layoutAlgorithm: {
                        enableSimulation: false,
                        integration: 'verlet',
                        linkLength: 100
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                id: 'language-tree',
                marker: {
                    radius: 13
                },
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    textPath: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    linkFormat: '',
                    allowOverlap: false
                },
                nodes: nodes,
                data: links
            }]
        }
    }
```